# Is this code correct

Tags: python

I have a question to ask, please. Given the code below, can you please let me know why in manager (or in the worker) class why

```
self.FirstName
```

gives the same result as

```
self._firstName
```

I would have thought that `self._firstName` would not be accessible in either of the classes (Manager/Worker) since it local to the Employee class and should not be accessible outside it, no ?

Please suggest.

```
import gc

class Employee(object):
    """Employee Base Class"""
    def __init__(self, FirstName, LastName,Age, Role):
        super(Employee, self).__init__()
        self._firstName = FirstName
        self._lastName = LastName
        self._age = Age
        self._role = Role

    @property
    def FirstName(self):
        return self._firstName

    @property
    def Age(self):
        return self._age

    @property
    def Role(self):
        return self._role

    @FirstName.setter
    def FirstName(self, value):
        self._firstName = value;
        pass

    @Role.setter 
    def Role(self, value):
        self._role = value;
        pass


class Manager(Employee):
    """Manager class"""
    def __init__(self, FirstName,LastName,Age):
        Employee.__init__(self,FirstName, LastName, Age, 'Manager')
        # super(Manager, self).__init__()

    def getParents(self):
        """Get parents of the class"""
        print(gc.get_referrers(self))
        pass

    def ManagerInfo(self):
        print("FirstName : " + self.FirstName)
        print("Role : " + self.Role)
        print("Age : " + str(self.Age))



class Worker(Employee):
    """docstring for Worker"""
    def __init__(self, FirstName, LastName, Age):
        Employee.__init__(self,FirstName, LastName, Age, 'employee')

    def getParents(self):
        """Get parents of the class"""
        print(gc.get_referrers(self))
        pass

    def WorkerInfo(self):
        print("FirstName : " + self.FirstName)
        print("Role : " + self.Role)
        print("Age : " + str(self.Age))
        pass


# manager = Employee('John','Doe' , 40, 'Manager')
# print("{0}'s age is {1} years.".format(manager.FirstName, manager.Age))
anEmp = Worker('WorkerName', 'LastName', 20)
aManager = Manager('John', 'Doe', 40)

print(anEmp.WorkerInfo())
print(anEmp.getParents())
print("----------------------------")
print(aManager.ManagerInfo())
print(aManager.getParents())
```

Thanks

Comment: Possibly better suited to [codereview.se], but read their guidelines before posting.

Comment: Why the downvotes ??  Something wrong with the question?? I have seen other question asking for reviews, which is why I asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why `self.FirstName` gives the same result as `self._firstName`

Because you defined `FirstName` as a `property` returning `self._firstname`. What did you expect actually ?

> I would have thought that self._firstName would not be accessible in either of the classes (Manager/Worker) since it local to the Employee class

It's not 'local to the Employee class', it's an attribute of `Employee` *instances* (it doesn't exist in the `Employee` class itself).

> and should not be accessible outside it, no ?

While prefixing a name with a single underscore denotes an implementation attribute (IOW something that is NOT part of the public API - the equivalent of 'protected' in most mainstream languages), it doesn't prevent access to the attribute. Actually there's absolutely NO enforcement of access restriction in Python, it's all convention (and eventually name mangling for `__pseudoprivates` names).

Python's philosophy is that we are all consenting adults and are wise enough to not do stupid things like messing with what is clearly labelled as an implementation attribute without accepting full responsability for breaking encapsulation.

> can you please let me know what I should be doing in order to make sure that the user can only set the value using the setters and not by doing self._firstName

Nothing more than you already did actually. Re-read the above paragraphs, I already mentionned that Python did  **NOT** enforced access restriction of any kind. `self._firstname` is prefixed with a single leading underscore, which is the way to tell "this is an implemention detail and not part of the API, you should not be messing with this attribute, you should not even know it exists, so if you break something by messing with it well too bad for you dude, but you're on your own".

> so if in case, I have some arbitrary logic that manipulates the value in the setter before setting it, the updated value will not be available if the user just does self._firstName instead of self.FirstName

The chances this would happen are rather low actually (and that's an understatement) but theoritically yes this *could* happen. **But** this is totally unrelated since you'd have the very same problem if the user used `self.FirstName` instead since it would *still* return the stale value...

Comment: Might be useful to link to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).

Comment: @bruno .. Thanks for the valuable comments. In that case, can you please let me know what I should be doing in order to make sure that the user can only set the value using the setters and not by doing self._firstName. Sorry I have a limited understanding of python.

Comment: @bruno any article/post/link with code samples will be helpful. thanks

Comment: You can't block the access to an attribute. The leading underscore gives a hint, that the attribute is an impementation detail and _should_ not be used. That's enough. We're all consenting adults here.

Comment: @Matthias: Thanks for letting me know. One additional question please - so if in case, I have some arbitrary logic that manipulates the value in the setter before setting it, the updated value will not be available if the user just does self._firstName instead of self.FirstName. This will result in logical error, no? Sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: @Gagan: Correct. Of course there are things like descriptors that might help blocking the access. But the final rule: If someone wants to intercept the way the program works, he can! Some see this as a weakness of Python, most Python developers see this as a strength.

Comment: @Matthias: Thank You, Sir. Much appreciated.